# Cant use column label value in "MAX(CASE WHEN value ='first_name' THEN value END) as 'Förnamn'

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, case, aggregate-functions

The column name in the table i wish to use is "value" but when in MySql it becomes a MySql command. Column name "slug" work just fine. I have no control over the column name so i cant change it the sourcetable.

Is there a way to use value instead og slug?

```
MAX(CASE WHEN **value** ='first_name' THEN value END) as 'Förnamn',

ID---+---EntryID---+--- slug---+---value---
1           1         first_name    Luke
2           1         lastname      Skywalker
3           1         profession    Jedi

SELECT entry_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN slug ='first_name' THEN slug END) as 'Förnamn',
MAX(CASE WHEN slug ='last_name' THEN slug END) as 'hej',
MAX(CASE WHEN slug ='email_address' THEN slug END) as 'E-post'
FROM wpgl_cf_form_entry_values
GROUP BY entry_id
```

Comment: MAX(CASE WHEN SLUG ='first_name' THEN value END) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you just want conditional aggregation, like so

```
SELECT entry_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN slug ='first_name'    THEN value END) as `Förnamn`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN slug ='last_name'     THEN value END) as `hej`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN slug ='email_address' THEN value END) as `E-post`
FROM wpgl_cf_form_entry_values
GROUP BY entry_id
```

Note: don't use single quotes for identifiers: these should be reserved for literal strings only. MySQL uses backticks for identifiers (although, in general, I would recommend using identifiers that do not require quoting).